# How can i write a statement for reaching end of list my if block

Tags: python, data-science, data-mining

I want calculate for all columns of my dataset and i write a for loop including if statament
i reached 1001, 1000, 526 wiht value_counts() of dataset but the problem is;
1001 is an categorical column dont look the numbers its just value_counts of a columns
but i have three(3) columns with 526 value counts and my loop don't look other 2 columns because its understand a for loop contuining how can i reach end of my list or how should i write a statement for my if statament

`entropy_list =[]`

`categorical_data = [x for x in avustralya_hava_data.columns if avustralya_hava_data[x].dtypes == "O"]`

```
for i in avustralya_hava_data[categorical_data].columns:
    
    #if avustralya_hava_data[i].dtypes == "O":
       
    c_data_copy = avustralya_hava_data[i].value_counts()  
    print(c_data_copy, "\n")
    print("******************")
    entropy = 0    
    for l in range(len(c_data_copy)):
        p = (c_data_copy[l]/row)
        entropy += (-math.log(p,2)*(p))
        print(c_data_copy[l]," degeri icin entropi ","--->",entropy)
        
        if c_data_copy[l] == c_data_copy[len(c_data_copy) - 1]:
            entropy_list.append(entropy)
            print("\n","Entropi list :" ,entropy_list, "\n")
            print("******************")

1001  degeri icin entropi  ---> 5.273858120932727
1000  degeri icin entropi  ---> 5.389344990008679
526  degeri icin entropi  ---> 5.46014617420736

 Entropi list : [5.46014617420736] 

******************
526  degeri icin entropi  ---> 5.53094735840604

 Entropi list : [5.46014617420736, 5.53094735840604] 

******************
526  degeri icin entropi  ---> 5.601748542604721

 Entropi list : [5.46014617420736, 5.53094735840604, 5.601748542604721]
```

Comment: You go through indexes in your loop, so just check if index is correct, not row - `if l == len(c_data_copy)-1` (Also, I'd suggest using another variable for the index. `l` is very similar to `1`. Common variable for loop is `i` as it doesn't have anything it's similar to and it usually means index anyway)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.